# JavaScript show only part of elements, random generate

Tags: javascript, random, hide, element, random-seed

I'm trying to make HTML game, which part is set of answers. I don't want whole set to be shown at one session, i want it to be chosen random (from 30 only 6 are shown).

```
<div id = "answers">
        <li class = "paris"><p> Champ Elysees </p></li>
        <li class = "london"><p> Tate Modern </p></li>
        <li class = "barcelona"><p> Sagrada Familia </p></li>
        <li class = "paris"><p> Montmartre </p></li>
        <li class = "ny"><p> Fifth Avenue </p></li>
        <li class = "barcelona"><p> Paella </p></li>
        <li class = "barcelona"><p> La Rambla </p></li>
        <li class = "london"><p> Piccadilly Circus </p></li>
        <li class = "paris"><p> Mona Lisa </p></li>
        <li class = "ny"><p> Empire State Building </p></li>
        <li class = "ny"><p> Broadway </p></li>
        <li class = "paris"><p> Musée d'Orsay </p></li>
        <li class = "ny"><p> Wall Street </p></li>
        <li class = "london"><p> Camden Town </p></li>
        <li class = "ny"><p> Big Apple </p></li>
        <li class = "barcelona"><p> La Boqueria </p></li>
    </div>
```

My question is: how can I hide this elements and show only part of them by random generate?

Answer (score 2):

You can loop through the list and hide them at random by getting all of the `li` nodes and adjusting the `hidden` property:

```js
document.querySelectorAll("#answers li")
.forEach(answer => 
  answer.hidden = Boolean( Math.random() < 0.5 ) 
);
```

```html
<div id = "answers">
        <li class = "paris"><p> Champ Elysees </p></li>
        <li class = "london"><p> Tate Modern </p></li>
        <li class = "barcelona"><p> Sagrada Familia </p></li>
        <li class = "paris"><p> Montmartre </p></li>
        <li class = "ny"><p> Fifth Avenue </p></li>
        <li class = "barcelona"><p> Paella </p></li>
        <li class = "barcelona"><p> La Rambla </p></li>
        <li class = "london"><p> Piccadilly Circus </p></li>
        <li class = "paris"><p> Mona Lisa </p></li>
        <li class = "ny"><p> Empire State Building </p></li>
        <li class = "ny"><p> Broadway </p></li>
        <li class = "paris"><p> Musée d'Orsay </p></li>
        <li class = "ny"><p> Wall Street </p></li>
        <li class = "london"><p> Camden Town </p></li>
        <li class = "ny"><p> Big Apple </p></li>
        <li class = "barcelona"><p> La Boqueria </p></li>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try creating an array of indexes of all the elements, then sort the array and slice only part you want. Finally loop through all the elements to show/hide based on the *index*.

You can try the following way:

```js
function RandomDiv() {
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll('#answers li');
  var indArr= new Array(elements.length).fill().map((_,i)=>i);
  // Shuffle array
  var shuffled = indArr.sort(function(){return .5 - Math.random()});
  // Get sub-array of first 5 elements after shuffled
  var selected = shuffled.slice(0, 5);
  elements.forEach((el,i) => {
    if(selected.includes(i))
      el.style.display='block';
    else el.style.display='none';
  });
}
RandomDiv();
```

```html
<div id = "answers">
  <li class = "paris"><p> Champ Elysees </p></li>
  <li class = "london"><p> Tate Modern </p></li>
  <li class = "barcelona"><p> Sagrada Familia </p></li>
  <li class = "paris"><p> Montmartre </p></li>
  <li class = "ny"><p> Fifth Avenue </p></li>
  <li class = "barcelona"><p> Paella </p></li>
  <li class = "barcelona"><p> La Rambla </p></li>
  <li class = "london"><p> Piccadilly Circus </p></li>
  <li class = "paris"><p> Mona Lisa </p></li>
  <li class = "ny"><p> Empire State Building </p></li>
  <li class = "ny"><p> Broadway </p></li>
  <li class = "paris"><p> Musée d'Orsay </p></li>
  <li class = "ny"><p> Wall Street </p></li>
  <li class = "london"><p> Camden Town </p></li>
  <li class = "ny"><p> Big Apple </p></li>
  <li class = "barcelona"><p> La Boqueria </p></li>
</div>
<button id="btnNext" onclick="RandomDiv()">Next</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will let you choose how many you want to hide. In this case, we hide 14 of the 16 answers randomly by grabbing the elements from the page, shuffling them, and hiding the first 14 from the shuffled elements:

```js
var answerElements = document.getElementById("answers").getElementsByTagName("li");
var shuffledAnswerElements = randoSequence(answerElements);
for (var i = 0; i < Math.min(14, shuffledAnswerElements.length); i++) {
  shuffledAnswerElements[i].value.style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://randojs.com/1.0.0.js"></script>
<div id = "answers">
 <li class = "paris"><p> Champ Elysees </p></li>
 <li class = "london"><p> Tate Modern </p></li>
 <li class = "barcelona"><p> Sagrada Familia </p></li>
 <li class = "paris"><p> Montmartre </p></li>
 <li class = "ny"><p> Fifth Avenue </p></li>
 <li class = "barcelona"><p> Paella </p></li>
 <li class = "barcelona"><p> La Rambla </p></li>
 <li class = "london"><p> Piccadilly Circus </p></li>
 <li class = "paris"><p> Mona Lisa </p></li>
 <li class = "ny"><p> Empire State Building </p></li>
 <li class = "ny"><p> Broadway </p></li>
 <li class = "paris"><p> Musée d'Orsay </p></li>
 <li class = "ny"><p> Wall Street </p></li>
 <li class = "london"><p> Camden Town </p></li>
 <li class = "ny"><p> Big Apple </p></li>
 <li class = "barcelona"><p> La Boqueria </p></li>
</div>
```

This code uses [randojs.com](https://randojs.com) to simplify the randomness (i.e. the shuffling) and make it easier to read, so if you want to use this code, just make sure to paste this in the head tag of your html document:

```
<script src="https://randojs.com/1.0.0.js"></script>
```

Comment: Why choose to use a library for this?

Comment: it's just preference. i use randojs as a go-to for pretty much all my randomness because it's reliable, super lightweight, simple, and very readable. but different strokes for different folks- there are other answers here if you prefer them